# I have a markdown file that has errors and need to use a python3.12 to find the errors

Tags: python-3.x, markdown

I have a markdown file that has syntax errors and I want to be able to find all the errors.  I am able to get the list of errors by using the **pymarkdownlnt** library locally using the terminal, however, I am trying to use Python 3.12 to accomplish the task.  **pymarkdownlnt** library has been depreciated.

This is what I am tired and having no luck.  I am trying to figure out which library will work with Python 3.12 to accomplish this task.    Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import subprocess
import json

file_path = "~/Documents/Project"
def lint_markdown_file(file_path):
    command = ['markdownlint', '-s', '-j', file_path]
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()

    if process.returncode != 0:
        # Handle linting errors
        error_message = error.decode().strip() if error else output.decode().strip()
        print('Linting errors:', error_message)
    else:
        # Parse linting results
        lint_results = json.loads(output.decode().strip())
        if lint_results:
            print('Linting errors:')
            for result in lint_results:
                print(f"Line {result['lineNumber']}: {result['ruleNames'][0]} - {result['ruleDescription']}")
        else:
            print('No linting errors.')

# Usage example
lint_markdown_file('text.md')
```

I am getting error

````
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/markdownlint", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('pymarkdownlint==0.3.1', 'console_scripts', 'markdownlint')())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/markdownlint", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 202, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymarkdownlint/cli.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pymarkdownlint.config import LintConfig
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymarkdownlint/config.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
Ashish@MacBook-Pro-2 Project %```
````

Comment: Python 3.12 is still in alpha. Why do you **have** to use it?

Comment: this is part of an interview where they want to see how I can use 3.12 ver to find all the errors in markdown file.

Comment: i updated the traceback in the body of the message, since i am limited on the characters here.

Comment: @DavidBuck any thoughs?

Comment: @DeepSpace any thoughs?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known bug in the library. In fact, a proposed fix can be found in [Pull Request 9](https://github.com/jorisroovers/pymarkdownlint/pull/9) of the project on GitHub. Unfortunately, it appears that the fix was never merged or released. This is one of the problems with using an abandoned project.

Specifically, notice that last few lines of your traceback:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymarkdownlint/config.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

This indicates that on line 2 of `pymarkdownlint/config.py` we find the line of code: `import ConfigParser`. However, that line is raising the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'`. In fact, that is correct. The module in the Python Standard Library is [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/configparser.html) (all lowercase).

A look as Pull Request 9 of the project we can see that only one [change](https://github.com/jorisroovers/pymarkdownlint/pull/9/files) is proposed. Specifically, `ConfigParser` is replaced with `configparser` in the file `pymarkdownlint/config.py`.

```
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
  from pymarkdownlint import rules
- import ConfigParser
+ import configparser
  from collections import OrderedDict

  import os
```

Presumably, this change would need to be made to the copy of the library you have locally. However, if such a simple bug exists, what other issues may be lurking below the surface? You may be better served by looking for something other than this library.

Comment: BTW, while researching this answer, I searched for the library, and found a different library with a similar name: [pymarkdownlnt](https://pypi.org/project/pymarkdownlnt/). This appears to be more complete and better maintained. Note sure if it would better meet your needs.